# Is it possible to persist a DSL Java object with JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, dsl

I have a DSL Java object, i.e. a POJO which returns `this` in setters plus the getters/setters have an unusual naming pattern:

```
public class Demo {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Date created;

    public Demo id (long value) { id = value; return this; }
    public String id () { return id; }
    public Demo name (String value) { name = value; return this; }
    public String name () { return name; }
    public Demo created (Date value) { created = value; return this; }
    public Date created () { 
        if (created == null) created = new Date ();

        return created;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to tell JPA to use "name(String)" and "name()" as the setter/getter method?

[EDIT] My issue is the `created` field above. For this field, I want JPA to use the "getter" `created()` so the field will always be non-NULL.

Or is there a way to tell JPA to use `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` when creating a new object with `created == null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the JPA spec (see [JSR-220](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr220/index.html)) chapter 2.1.1 you can tell JPA to use field access instead of property access by annotating the fields for mapping information and not the getter methods.

I don't think you can tell JPA which naming convention to use for getters and setters since it's a basic java beans concept.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention you have to use annotations. Don't know if it works with xml mapping. :-/

Comment: And if I don't want to use the property access?

Comment: That's what I mentioned. Put the annotations before the fields. Now after you edited your post the problem remain, that "created" could be null. I think you could use the attribute "columDefinition" of the @Column annotation to define a default value for this column (see chapter 9.1.5 of the mentioned spec).

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply intialise `created` when you define in the class, and then use field access.

```
private Date created = new Date();
```

Comment: Because in my case, new Date() is an expensive operation :) I really want to do this lazily.